# How can I connect a bunch of TPoints with a polyline without self-intersections?

Tags: delphi

I have an array of `TPoints` and I want to draw the `trellis` that passes through all these points `without intersecting itself`.
Is there any algorithm available?

Comment: First, I think you need to clarify what you mean. What exactly is a "trellis" in this case? Second, if you think about it, this is not a Delphi question, but a pure mathematics (algorithm) question.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand,"trellis" is another word for polyline. I'm looking for a Delphi coded algorithm. I suppose that somebody/somewhere could have/been developed one.

Comment: I still don't get it. If the input is any arbitrary array of points, "the trellis" may not exist, i.e., it is not at all certain that there exists a unique polyline that (1) passes through every point and (2) does not self intersect. I mean, if the points are (0, 0) and (1, 1), one possibility is the line from (0, 0) to (1, 1); another is the line from (-1, -1) to (55, 55). So which do you want? Maybe you mean "a trellis" instead of "the trellis"? (This is not grammatical nitpicking. When you discuss algorithms, mathematical precision is absolutely necessary.) Or do you also require...

Comment: ...that the polyline only starts, ends, and "turns" at a point? If so, you need to make that clear! But even in this case, neither existence nor uniqueness is guaranteed. And in every case, this absolutely is a math Q, not a Delphi Q. The algorithm could be implemented in any language, and trivially converted between languages. The only reason one could insist on a particular language in a case like this is if your real Q is "please write the code for me" or "please recommend a library". In both cases, the Q would be off-topic at SO.

Comment: (Well, existence probably isn't an issue. But uniqueness certainly is.)

Comment: Let's say I have the GPS/2D coordinates of the contour of a building complex and I want to draw the contour of the building via code. How to automatically join 2D points ? Ιt's a math question as you say but I was hoping there was some kind of library in Delphi.

Comment: Oh, then you also want to draw lines between points that are close to each other? That actually completely changes the question! Had you not made that clarification, you might have ended up with algorithms that indeed produce a non-intersecting polyline connecting the dots, but which is very far from the one you'd like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTkY6.png I hope you now see the importance of mathematical precision!

Comment: Thanks AndreasRejbrand. Now I can see it's a difficult case and I must search hard for a solution.

Comment: Have you acquired these GPS coordinates yourself or gotten them from sombrere else? If you are acquiring these coordinates yourself  by logging them using GPS make sure you do so in a specific order like going around the building complex in clockwise or anticlockwise order. This way you make yourself the said task a lot easier since you already have specific order for connecting coordinates.

Comment: @SilverWarior. No, the order is random anyway, since it's not possible to just follow the building path because you have to count mixed objects on the same path. I found the solution for most cases, when the building has a curved outline (no recesses). In this case the solution is to find the `convex hull` of the points and there are algorithms in other languages. If someone knows something similar in Delphi, please post it. For the indented perimeter cases, I'm still looking into that. PS the distinction of the building from other objects is based on a name given by the GPS operator

Comment: Basic algorithm could be:
while numPoints > 0 do
    Find the convex hull points
    connect these points 
    remove the points from the bucket
end;

or... Triangulate the points (e.g. Delauny Triangulation) and connect neighouring triangles - maybe these need to be sorted from left to right or in "clock" direction

Comment: @JimPapas For buildings that have no recesses you could simply search for nearest points. Pick some staring point and calculate distance to every other point. Then draw a line from your starting point to the nearest one. Then recalculate distance from that point to others skipping the starting point and again connect to the closest one. You repeat this this process skipping all the already processed points. Depending of the size of recess this might work even for some buildings that do contain recesses.